# I want to trigger functions when user information is updated in B2C

Tags: azure, azure-functions, signalr, azure-ad-b2c

I want to trigger functions when user information is updated in B2C.
However, I could not find a sample. Is this possible? The process is as follows.

1. Change the user's name in Azure AD B2C
2. azure functions fire when updated

Comment: How do you change the name in B2C ?Is it self service, from an API ?

Comment: It depends on how you change the name. If via a custom policy, then you can add a REST API call to the flow.

Comment: I want to change manually through azure portal.
From what I have found, it seems that B2C cannot be used as a trigger for FUNCTIONS.
Do you know if this is the case, or is it possible to trigger using the B2C audit log?
Evnet hubs etc,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we cannot trigger AZURE FUNCTIONS when any information regarding B2C users is updated as of now.

Instead, an alternate approach can be used, by using Azure Timer Trigger FunctionApps. The FuncApp will hit the Azure Portal to get the User information.

For example, the following API will get the B2C users whose accounts are disabled every time the FuncApp is executed.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=accountEnabled eq false